# Fixed width div losing its background-color upon resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css, resize, background-color

I am creating a blog based on the 960 grid system. It has three simple divs:

1. header 2. Content 3. Footer and each of them has a fixed width div which holds 2-3 columns of text. The content div, and the fixed width div inside it have the same background color, but when i reduce the size of the browser window, for some reason it ignores the content div's color and reveals the color of the html body.

here's an example of another website where it happens: http://encourageothers.com/ ... reduce the size of the browser to something less than 900 px or so, and scroll horizontally to the right ... u will see what I mean.

Please help me! ... This is driving me nuts!!

Comment: This happens because the <body> tag's CSS "width" property is set to 100% (the default on all pages), which is the length of the browser's viewport. When you scroll horizontally, you go beyond 100%, where the body tag "stops". I haven't found a way to fix this, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jake is absolutely right with the 100% width related to the viewport of the browser.

instead of adding an additional max-width, add an additional MIN-width to the div showing the resize-problem. if your smallest width, before the scrollbar appears, is 1200px - just give the div in question a min-width of 1200px.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! ... just set a max-width in pixels and also a width in 100% wherever u see this problem. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this problem.

Setting a width (in pixels) on the div container can lead to overflow problems. The same is true if you use **rem** or **em**. I needed a different solution.

My solution is to set display:inline-block; on the div container & wrap it in a div.

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
.container {
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
bodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybodybod
<div>
    <div class="container">
        divdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdivdiv
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: partial or cut-off background on browser window resize with scroll]

The above image shows what the problem looks like. To re-create the problem, just set display:block; on the container div & resize the browser window until you see the scrollbar on the bottom, then move the scrollbar all the way to the right.

As you probably noticed, the issue does not occur on the body tag when it has a background. But it does occur on the div tag with a red background.

Comment: A simpler solution might be to just add display:inline-block; on the body tag.